# What does the jlink option "--strip-native-commands" do?

Tags: java, jlink, jpackage

I found nothing about `--strip-native-commands` using `jlink --help` (doesn't even list it as an option) or even in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html). I have not found any documentation for it online, but using `jpackage -h` tells me:

```
--jlink-options <jlink options>
          A space separated list of options to pass to jlink
          If not specified, defaults to "--strip-native-commands
          --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files".
          This option can be used multiple times.
          ...
          ...
          If --runtime-image is not specified, jpackage will run jlink to
          create the runtime image using options:
          --strip-debug, --no-header-files, --no-man-pages, and
          --strip-native-commands.
```

There seems to be nothing about `--strip-native-commands` online. Using it seems to shrink the runtime a little bit:

```
34612   ncnotstripped
34568   ncstripped
```

But I want to be aware of any potential trade-offs. What does "native commands" refer to? What am I removing from my runtime to make it smaller?

Comment: It's also in the Java 9 Oracle docs for Jlink. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/jlink.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options and documentation for `jlink` are "hidden" behind `--list-plugins`. If you execute:

```
jlink --list-plugins
```

You'll see:

> ```
>  --strip-native-commands   Exclude native commands (such as java/java.exe)
>                            from the image.
> ```

At least in version 21.0.1 on Windows.